# Why won't the which function return every element I request?

Tags: r

I have the following list in R, and I'm trying to extract all values from A$a that are greater than 3 using which(). I've tried the following:

```
A = list(a = c(2:5), b = c(3:5), c = c(4:6))
which(A$a > 3)
```

For some reason, it returns a vector of 3 and 4, and it excludes 5. How can I make which() return all values in A$a that are greater than 3?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

3 and 4 means the 3rd and 4th elements of `A$a` are greater than 3. The 3rd and 4th elements of `A$a` are `4` and `5`.

If you want the elements themselves:

```
A$a[which(A$a > 3)]
```

Or just

```
A$a[A$a > 3]
```